# Adding sync option to a initialized FlexSlider

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, flexslider

I am trying to add **sync** option after `#slider` initialization but it does not work. Other options like **animationSpeed** works fine.

```js
jQuery( function( $ ) {
  // The slider being synced must be initialized first
  $('#carousel').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false,
    itemWidth: 210,
    itemMargin: 5,
    asNavFor: '#slider'
  });
 
  // Assume that it's defined in a 3rd-party plugin
  $('#slider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide",
    controlNav: false,
    animationLoop: false,
    slideshow: false
  });
  
  // Now I want to customize the options after init.
  var slider = $('#slider').data('flexslider');
  slider.vars.sync = '#carousel';
   slider.vars.animationSpeed = 5000;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider/master/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<link href="https://rawgit.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider/master/flexslider.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Place somewhere in the <body> of your page -->
<div id="slider" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" />
    </li>
    <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
  <ul class="slides">
    <li>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" />
    </li>
    <li>
      <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300" />
    </li>
    <!-- items mirrored twice, total of 12 -->
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Expected result:** If the sync option is set correctly, the first slider sync with carousel which is not working obviously in above example.

Comment: Why downvote? I provided an example and my problem is specific.